# WPF Binding Path=/ not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I've set up my `DataContext` like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <c:DownloadManager />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Where `DownloadManager` is `Enumerable<DownloadItem>`. Then I set my `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=/}" ...
```

So that it should list all the DownloadItems, right? So I should be able to set my columns like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Uri, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Where `Uri` is a property of the `DownloadItem`. But it doesn't seem to like this. In the visual property editor, it doesn't recognize `Uri` is a valid property, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

It was working before, when I had the data grid binding to `Values`, but then I took that enumerable out of the `DownloadManager` and made itself enumerable. How do I fix this?

PS: By "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't list any items. I've added some to the constructor of the DM, so it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: `Path=/` tries to find a property of the `DownloadManager` called `/` - that's never going to be right.  (If it was an `XmlDataSource` you could use `XPath=/`, but that's a whole different story...)

Comment: @Dan: Ah.. I just chose "Current Item" from the property editor, and that's what it gave me.

Comment: @Dan - Path=/ will bind to the current item in the DataContext (when 
DataContext is a collection). Here's a good resource I use quite often when referring to Binding paths: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx

Comment: @Metro: Then why does `{Binding}` work but `{Binding Path=/}` not work?

Comment: see my answer I provided as an addendum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. It should be enough.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Or `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"`. Both do the same job.

Answer (score 6):

In response to the OP's question of why {Binding} works, but {Binding Path=/} does not work, I'm adding the following info as an answer to clarify the difference.

The following is taken from [MSDN Data Binding Overview > Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections):

> **Current Item Pointers**
>
> Views also support the notion of a
>   current item. You can navigate through
>   the objects in a collection view. As
>   you navigate, you are moving an item
>   pointer that allows you to retrieve
>   the object that exists at that
>   particular location in the collection.
>   For an example, see [How to: Navigate
>   Through the Objects in a Data
>   CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754244.aspx).
>
> Because WPF binds to a collection only
>   by using a view (either a view you
>   specify, or the collection's default
>   view), all bindings to collections
>   have a current item pointer. When
>   binding to a view, the slash ("/")
>   character in a Path value designates
>   the current item of the view. In the
>   following example, the data context is
>   a collection view. The first line
>   binds to the collection. The second
>   line binds to the current item in the
>   collection. The third line binds to
>   the Description property of the
>   current item in the collection.

```
<Button Content="{Binding }" />
<Button Content="{Binding Path=/}" />
<Button Content="{Binding Path=/Description}" />
```

Comment: Ohhh..... okay. Now I get it. Current Item != DataContext. It's the first item *in* the DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative sol'n to Danko's answer, I discovered Static Resources! (I'm a WPF noob)

```
<Window x:Class="ImageGetGUI.MainWindow"
    ...
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:DownloadManager x:Key="dm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource dm}" ...
```

Comment: You can also name your Window.DataContext, i.e., 
`<Window.DataContext> <c:DownloadManager x:Name="dm" /> </Window.DataContext>`  This will allow you to access the DataContext by name in your code behind if needed. You may also want to take a look at an ObjectDataProvider; I've found them immensely helpful when placed in the application's resource dictionary. For example, when you have a collection that is re-used on multiple views, i.e., a `List<US States>`.